# is there any functions for counting up groups in query result?

Tags: plsql

This is a query:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM Points 
WHERE i_id IN (1, 22, 579, 5887) AND i_requirement_id is not null 
GROUP BY i_requirement_id
```

I get count of requirement in each group.

I need to get count of all groups.

for example from next table

```
i_id     i_requirement_id
1         1022
22        1022
579       1059
5887      1022
```

I get 3 and 1 in result. But I need to get only 2 because in table I have only 2 groups of i_requrement_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something along the line of

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT i_requirement_id)
FROM Points 
WHERE i_id IN (1, 22, 579, 5887) AND i_requirement_id is not null
```

The **distinct** clause allow you for counting only different items

Comment: Sorry but I'm trying to evade queries like this. I used this variant like fill-in. I hoped that someone tell me a function for that.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't like Fabio's solution?  It is good enough.
The second way is using analytic function.

```
SELECT 
  i_requirement_id, 
  count(*) as count_inside_group,
  count(i_requirement_id) over() as count_of_groups
FROM Points 
WHERE i_id IN (1, 22, 579, 5887) AND i_requirement_id is not null 
GROUP BY i_requirement_id
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/54bd7/1)